# Change percentages to Real numbers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to convert percentages to real decimal numbers so they'll display properly. I tried  to_real() but maybe I did something wrong. Any suggestions?

[image: Percentage to real]

Comment: just do a simple display change. not a calculation.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.. could you explain further?

Comment: You can do it on the fly just with label expression. In the layer properties for labels next to the input for column name there is expression button. Click on it and use replace("YourColumn",'%','')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you just want to display as number in the label**

You can do it on the fly just with label expression. In the layer properties for labels next to the input for column name there is expression button. Click on it and use **replace("YourColumn",'%','')**

**If you need new column as number**

You can do the same to create new decimal number column with field calculator - expression **replace("YourColumn",'%','')**. You do not need to use **toreal** in this case as far as you are just saving that value as new number column. Conversion toreal is useful in the case you need to do some addition calculation like: **toreal(replace("YourColumn",'%','')) + 50.50**

Comment: @Chris Could you please accept this answer in that case? (check at left top corner of my answer). Thank you :)